# Retrieve relations using specific coordinates in an overpass query

Tags: openstreetmap, api, overpass-api

I'm new to Overpass API. I would like to make a query that retrieves the relations on natural=water using specific coordinates. I tried the following query:

```
(
  way["natural"="water"]({{bbox}});
  relation["natural"="water"]({{bbox}});
  ( ._; >; );
);

out geom;
```

I got the ways and relations. However, if I use the same query but instead of `{{bbox}}`, I write my coordinates, it does not work. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check for the correct order of your coordinates. The correct order for the Overpass bbox is `south,west,north,east`, i..e, latitude of the southern edge, longitude of the western edge,  latitude of the norther edge, longitude of the eastern edge.

In overpass turbo you can also check which bbox has been used: Click on Export / raw data. This will return a link to the Overpass API query where the `{{bbox}}` keyword has been replaced with coordinates.